# LUKS: Change --pbkdf arguments without reformat?

Tags: luks, cryptsetup

I find it cool that you can change the passphrase and even have multiple keyslots with LUKS. But can you change the pbkdf after formatting?

When running `luksFormat` you give `--pbkdf` and arguments for that:

```
cryptsetup -y -v luksFormat --sector-size 4096 \
  --pbkdf-memory 4000000 --pbkdf argon2id --iter-time 300 \
  /dev/sda4
```

Is it possible to change these without dataloss?

E.g. change the --iter-time from 300 to 3000 to:

```
cryptsetup -y -v luksFormat --sector-size 4096 \
  --pbkdf-memory 4000000 --pbkdf argon2id --iter-time 3000 \
  /dev/sda4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify what arguments to use every time you add a key.

So simply add a new key and remove the old:

```
cryptsetup luksAddKey  --pbkdf-memory 4000000 --pbkdf argon2id --pbkdf-parallel 1 --iter-time 3000 /dev/sda4
```

Comment: works with luksAddKey, luksChangeKey, luksConvertKey (for keyslot specific settings) and you can change hash spec etc. for master key using cryptsetup-reencrypt --keep-key